# Find the positions of elements that are different from their next one in the list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, numpy

I want the position of element in the list where it is different from next element

```
nums = np.array(["cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","goldfish","bee","bee","cat","cat"])
```

So I use zip and enumerate within the list

```
print [c for a,b,c in zip(nums, nums[1:],enumerate(nums)) if a != b]
[(1, 'cat'), (4, 'dog'), (5, 'goldfish'), (7, 'bee')]
```

I want just the position

```
>>[1,4,5,7]
```

How to remove tuple here? Or is there a better (in term of faster) way to get the position of different element in the list?

Comment: `print [c[0] ...]` would to the trick nicely.

Comment: `[i for i,j in enumerate(nums[:-1]) if nums[i] != nums[i+1]]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply compare the 1-offsetted slices and get the non-matching indices -

```
np.flatnonzero(nums[1:] != nums[:-1])
```

Comment: Does Numpy have a different parse from regular Python? I'd assume that `nums[1:] != nums[:-1]` would evaluate to `False` before being passed into `np.flatnonzero()`.

Answering myself: `np.array.__ne__` returns a function for later evaluation, not a bool.

Comment: @KirkStrauser Well since the input is an array, `nums[1:] != nums[:-1]` would also be an array as it would perform element-wise comparison and then `flatnonzero` would pick the indices corresponding to True values. Now, `nums[1:] != nums[:-1]` with `nums` being a list give us just a scalar, which would be a reduction ANY output I think. So, in the sample case if `nums` were a list, it would be just a scalar True. Not sure if that answers your query tho.

Comment: It does, thanks! I've used numpy very little so I didn't think of it that way at first glance.

Answer (score 4):

If you are looking for a **non** numpy solution:

```
In [19]: a = ["cat","cat","dog","dog","dog","goldfish","bee","bee","cat","cat"]

In [20]: [x for x in range(len(a)-1) if a[x] != a[x+1]]
Out[20]: [1, 4, 5, 7]
```